# Reading the data to iterate over with \foreach from a file

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, external-files

I have a `\foreach` that should read the data points from a file. The points are stored in such a way that a simple copy paste would do. In fact, I don't want to do more than copy paste (if ever possible). I found that `\input` does not work. There are a couple solutions around but they seem to do more than copy-paste. Is there an "easy" way to achieve that?

document.tex:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \from/\to in { \input{data}; } %input does not work...
  {\draw [->] \from -- \to;}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

data.dat:

```
{(1,1)}/{(3,3)},
{(-1,1)}/{(-3,3)},
{(1,-1)}/{(3,-3)}%
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `catchfile`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
{(1,1)}/{(3,3)},
{(-1,1)}/{(-3,3)},
{(1,-1)}/{(3,-3)}%
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\loaddata{\jobname.dat}
\foreach \from/\to in \loadeddata{\draw [->] \from -- \to;}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With `\endlinechar=-1` we effectively remove the end-of-lines in the loaded file.

[image]

Comment: This works wonderful - and its the easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting approach. The problems you are encountering stem from the fact that each segment is on a separate line in `data.dat` and that the `\foreach` argument should be expanded first. The following reads the contents of the `data.dat` file (the `\loaddata` command, which is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111337/89497)) and appends each line to the end of the `\loadeddata` command, resulting in all of the data on a single line (`{(1,1)}/{(3,3)},{(-1,1)}/{(-3,3)},{(1,-1)}/{(3,-3)}%` in your example). This is then expanded and used as the argument in the `\foreach` call.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
{(1,1)}/{(3,3)},
{(-1,1)}/{(-3,3)},
{(1,-1)}/{(3,-3)}%
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
    \newread\dataread
    \def\loaddata#1{%
        \gdef\loadeddata{}%
        \openin\dataread=#1
        \begingroup\endlinechar=-1
        \@whilesw\unless\ifeof\dataread\fi{%
            \read\dataread to \dataline
            \edef\rslt{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\loadeddata{\dataline}}%
            \rslt%expanded argument
        }%
        \endgroup
        \closein\dataread
    }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \loaddata{data.dat}
    \edef\expfor{\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\from/\noexpand\to in {\loadeddata}}
    \expfor{\draw [->] \from -- \to;}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? **textmerg** can merge the data using the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  make line/.code args={#1/#2}{%
    \draw [->] #1 -- #2;
  },
}
\Fields{\myline}
\newcommand*\makeline[1]{%
  \tikzset{make line=#1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Merge{\jobname.dat}{
    \expandafter\makeline\expandafter{\myline}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: data lines]

Comment: Admittedly, it is not the wheel requested in the question as I don't use `\foreach` but that avoids a double-loop (or it appears to - don't know what **textmerg** does, mind).... (No idea if it is more or less efficient.)

Comment: Excellent point. Thanks for bringing `textmerg` to my attention!

Comment: Thanks. It is useful. I use it to merge output from spreadsheets saved as `.csv` files. Then I can merge the data into a template to produce forms or letters or whatever. It doesn't seem much used on this site, though.