# fill color after batch draw

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw some blocks with below code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
        \foreach \x in {-8, -7.4, -6.8, -6.2}
        \foreach \y in {1.8, 1.2, ..., -2.4}
            \draw (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can fill different color to each of them when I draw them one by one, but how can I fill after I draw them with this batch？ For example, I only want to fill some of them with red like picture shows below. (can I named each block as a node and I can fill by selecting the node name?)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can name the coordinates and then color it (using a background layer) after the fact.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
            % use layers to add shading "under" the rectangles
            \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
            \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
            \foreach[count=\ordx from 1] \x in {-8, -7.4, -6.8, -6.2}
            \foreach[count=\ordy from 1] \y in {1.8, 1.2, ..., -2.4}
            % name the top left and bottom right coordinate
            \draw (\x,\y) coordinate(TL-\ordx-\ordy) rectangle (\x+0.5,\y+0.5) coordinate(BR-\ordx-\ordy);
            % go on the background layer
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                % you can use your coordinates here; lot of possibilities
                % if you add the calc tikzlibrary
                \fill[red!20]  (TL-1-1) rectangle (BR-1-1);
                \fill[green!20]  (TL-3-1) rectangle (BR-3-1);
                \fill[red!70]  (TL-4-4) rectangle (BR-4-4);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The trick here is that you name the top left coordinate with `(TL-x-y)` y the corresponding bottom right `(BR-x-y)`, and then use them to add the filling in the background layer.

Notice that the node names are valid only in the same `tikzpicture`, unless you use the option `remember picture` (but then you have to take care of things like stretching and resizing, which is not trivial to manage)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use a matrix

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,row sep=1mm,column sep=1mm,
    nodes={minimum size=0.5cm,draw,anchor=center,outer sep=0},
    row 5 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=blue}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={fill=red!50}},
    row 3 column 1/.style={nodes={shade,right color=yellow}}
]{&&&\\&&&\\&&&\\&&&\\&&&\\&&&\\&&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The nodes inside a matrix are also automatically named.

Answer (score 5):

One way (pretty verbose) is to expand two loops into a single one, but loop over three variables (the coordinates and color):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
        \foreach \i / \j / \c in
          {0/6/red,   1/6/white, 2/6/white, 3/6/white,
           0/5/white, 1/5/white, 2/5/white, 3/5/white,
           0/4/white, 1/4/white, 2/4/white, 3/4/white,
           0/3/white, 1/3/white, 2/3/red,   3/3/white,
           0/2/white, 1/2/white, 2/2/white, 3/2/white,
           0/1/white, 1/1/red,   2/1/white, 3/1/red,
           0/0/white, 1/0/white, 2/0/white, 3/0/white}
           \filldraw[fill=\c] (-8+0.6*\i,1.8+0.6*\j) rectangle (-7.5+0.6*\i,1.3+0.6*\j);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can store the properties into a separate file (you can generate it programmatically), and do the following (the idea is taken from [Reading the data to iterate over with \foreach from a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283274/reading-the-data-to-iterate-over-with-foreach-from-a-file)):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
0/6/red,   1/6/white, 2/6/white, 3/6/white,
0/5/white, 1/5/white, 2/5/white, 3/5/white,
0/4/white, 1/4/white, 2/4/white, 3/4/white,
0/3/white, 1/3/white, 2/3/red,   3/3/white,
0/2/white, 1/2/white, 2/2/white, 3/2/white,
0/1/white, 1/1/red,   2/1/white, 3/1/red,
0/0/white, 1/0/white, 2/0/white, 3/0/white
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text centered]
        \loaddata{\jobname.dat}
        \foreach \i / \j / \c in \loadeddata
           \filldraw[fill=\c] (-8+0.6*\i,1.8+0.6*\j) rectangle (-7.5+0.6*\i,1.3+0.6*\j);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The file `\jobname.dat` is included into the main file for convenience only.

Comment: that means if I need draw hundreds of blocks, then I need write down each property of them like `0/6/red`?

Comment: That means that this solution wouldn't be a good one for the case of hundreds of blocks. I'd recommend to create the property list in a CSV file and use it in tikz picture.