# Flashcard automation

Tags: luatex, automation

I would like to prepare flashcards. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc, paperheight=18pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{vertcent}
{\newpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
{\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{vertcent}
    \begin{center}
        \Huge
        a book
    \end{center}
\end{vertcent}

\newpage

\begin{vertcent}
    \begin{center}
        \Huge
        a chair
    \end{center}
\end{vertcent}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to automate this process? Say I have a list of words (comma-separated, or a new entry in every line, etc.) and each entry is processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Usage, a comma-separated list: \makecards{card 1, card 2}:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc, paperheight=18pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,pgffor}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{vertcent}
{\newpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
{\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\newcommand{\makecards}[1]{%
    \foreach \c in {#1}{%
        \begin{vertcent}
           \begin{center}
                \Huge
                \c
            \end{center}
    \end{vertcent}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\makecards{a book,a chair}

\end{document}
```

## Update

If the desired comma-separated list is in an external file (in this case listtext.txt, which contains a comma-separated list) then this works (thanks to Rmano in [Tikz foreach does not work with \input or \directlua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570594/tikz-foreach-does-not-work-with-input-or-directlua)):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc, paperheight=18pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,pgffor,catchfile}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{vertcent}
{\newpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
{\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}

\newcommand{\makecards}[1]{%
    \loaddata{#1}
    \foreach \c in \loadeddata{%
        \begin{vertcent}
           \begin{center}
                \Huge
                \c
            \end{center}
    \end{vertcent}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\makecards{listtext.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update 2

It is simple to have a more complex `\foreach` statement using a forward slash to separate elements. The file `listtext2.txt` contains this:

```
a chair/living room,
a table/kitchen,
a lamp/bedroom,
something else/elsewhere,
and some more/some unknown place,
a horse/on a farm
```

And the code that typesets this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc, paperheight=18pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,pgffor,catchfile}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{vertcent}
    {\newpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
    {\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}

\newcommand{\makecards}[1]{%
    \loaddata{#1}%
    \foreach \c/\d in \loadeddata{%
        \begin{vertcent}
          \begin{center}
                \Huge
                \c\par  
                \vspace{.2in}
                \d
            \end{center}
    \end{vertcent}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\makecards{listtext2.txt}

\end{document}
```

...and produces the following:

[image]

I'd wondered how to do this -- now I know! Thanks.

Comment: I hope this does not warrant a separate question: Is it possible to have a flexibility such as: each line, say, contains two comma-separated entries, and I want them, say, displayed one below the other on the same page.

Comment: @blackened OK, I've added a second update.

Answer (score 4):

`csvsimple` allows you to process a file containing your entries as CSV:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
entry            ,
a book           ,
a chair          ,
a very long term ,
\end{filecontents*}

% This is a CSV file with only one column: each entry must be on it's own line **and** be followed by a comma 
% The first line is the header: the name of the column ("entry") will be assigned to command `\entry` below

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc, paperheight=18pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newenvironment{vertcent}
  {\newpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
  {\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\begin{document}
\csvreader{\jobname.csv}{entry=\entry}{%
  \begin{vertcent}
    \begin{center}
      \Huge\entry
    \end{center}
  \end{vertcent}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have latex code in your entries, enclose them in braces `{ \somecommand{text} } ,`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
entry               ,
{ \arb{ muslimuN} } ,
{ \arb{muslimAni} } ,
{ \arb{muslimUna} } ,
\end{filecontents*}

% This is a CSV file with only one column: each entry must be on it's own line **and** be followed by a comma 
% The first line is the header: the name of the column ("entry") will be assigned to command `\entry` below

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=32pc, paperheight=18pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabluatex}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newenvironment{vertcent}
  {\newpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}}
  {\vspace*{\fill}\newpage}

\begin{document}
\csvreader{\jobname.csv}{entry=\entry}{%
  \begin{vertcent}
    \begin{center}
      \Huge\entry
    \end{center}
  \end{vertcent}}
\end{document}
```

[image]