# Creating a user interface to control the contents of a document

Tags: formatting

I am searching for the easiest way possible to allow someone (who for example may not be strong with LaTeX) to control the contents of a specific document. To give more context, I am looking to create a collection of "main" documents with the same format, composed almost exclusively of different combinations of a set of about 30 "smaller" documents (each of these are essentially sections or subsections inside of the "main" documents). An important note is that the "smaller" documents often undergo minor updates, so they are called into the "main" documents from separate files (to avoid having to change many "main" documents by hand when small changes occur).

What I have arrived at thus far is a general "main" document which contains toggles in the preamble that control which "smaller" documents appear in the "main" document. Everything is working fine at this point, where the only step for the person creating the "main" documents is to comment "`%`" before `\toggletrue` in the preamble if they don't want that specific "smaller" document in the "main" document they are making (for example below "TheFirstDocument" wouldn't appear in the "main" document). Also what I have written below isn't meant to compile of course (missing files and packages), it is just to show a general example.

My question is, is there a way to create a very friendly user interface where perhaps the person making the "main" documents could just check off boxes of which "smaller" documents they wanted to include? If this isn't possible with LaTeX itself does anyone have suggestions of the easiest thing to turn to from here to achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Select Desired Documents %%%

\newtoggle{TheFirstDocument}
%\toggletrue{TheFirstDocument}

\newtoggle{TheSecondDocument}
\toggletrue{TheSecondDocument}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\iftoggle{TheFirstDocument}
{ExecuteMetaData[TheFirstDocument.tex]{tag}
}
{%nothing
}

\iftoggle{TheSecondDocument}
{ExecuteMetaData[TheSecondDocument.tex]{tag}
}
{%nothing
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this question might be helpful: [Importing Parameters From a Separate File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294117/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks that is definitely similar to what I was doing. However, my question is different in the sense that I am not really concerned with the "parent" document becoming muddled up. I am really just wondering about the possibility of creating a checklist (like this for example: http://www.contextures.com/images/datavalidation/datavallistboxprem10.png) so that the person creating the document doesn't have to write anything in LaTex at all, they can just tick off the "smaller" documents that they desire in the main one.

Comment: It wouldn't be very difficult to do this with a web form.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on that slightly more? I'm not very experienced with LaTeX or web forms and would appreciate it.

Comment: On the LaTeX side of things, what are these toggles and tags doing that `\input`/`\include` (or perhaps) `\includeonly` don't already do?

Comment: The tags were to import specific parts of the other files, and the toggles were used because there is actually other text in the body of document besides the imported files, and I found that using toggles allowed me to easily choose the location that the imported files appeared at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The LaTeX half of an answer:**

First, you can divide `Main.tex` into three files:

`InitMain.tex` contains the `\documentcalss`, some essential packages for the second file, and all the `\newtoggle`s you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{TheFirstDocument}
\newtoggle{TheSecondDocument}
```

The second file (`Main_A.tex`) `\input`s `InitMain.tex`, then contains all the `\toggletrue`s you need and finally `\input`s `Main.tex`

```
\input{InitMain}
\toggletrue{TheFirstDocument}
%\toggletrue{TheSecondDocument}
\input{Main}
```

And `Main.tex` can contain additional `\usepackage`s and other stuff you need. And of course you conditionally input the small documents here.

```
% additional preamble stuff

\begin{document}

\iftoggle{TheFirstDocument}
{\input{TheFirstDocument.tex}
}
{%nothing
}

\iftoggle{TheSecondDocument}
{\input{TheSecondDocument.tex}
}
{%nothing
}

\end{document}
```

Then you only need to compile `Main_A.tex` to get the final document.

With this, the users only have to edit the small file `Main_A.tex` and you could have files `Main_B.tex`, `Main_C.tex` and so on with different settings.

The other half of the answer depends on the operating system, available scripting languages, skills and more. You could write a script, which reads `Main_A.tex`, initialises the checkboxes and finally writes a new version with added or removed `%` signs. For example: on Windows jscript could be used to build a GUI like the one you showed. There you could even add a button, which calls, for exapmle, latexmk (never used this) to produce the final document directly from the dialog, provided there is a LaTeX installation on the computer.

Comment: I don't think I currently have the skill to do that but I suppose it's never too late to learn. In regards to picking which language to use, would you recommend trying jscript? What you described is pretty much exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Elijah: I mentioned jscript for two reasons: it can be used to build a dialog and it comes with Windows. The latter is a plus, because other solutions (Phyton comes to mind) require installing some software package on each PCs. But since I only did scripting with jscript so far, I can't draw comparisons.