# Read and process file content line by line with expl3

Tags: expl3, external-files, multiple-files

In a multi-file project organized as:

```
mainfile.tex
subfile1/subfile1.tex
subfile2/subfile2.tex
...
```

in order to make every subfile compilable on its own and make possible of referencing between subfiles, I'm currently using the package `xr` and write the following in the preamble of the subfiles:

```
\externaldocument{../subfile1/subfile1}
\externaldocument{../subfile2/subfile2}
...
```

but to avoid inputting the current file, I have to remove `\externaldocument{../subfile1/subfile1}` in `subfile1.tex`, remove `\externaldocument{../subfile2/subfile2}` in `subfile2.tex`, etc. This makes the preamble of the subfiles kind of hard to maintain when the number of files grows.

I wonder if this can be made automatic, that is to have a list of subfiles stored in `list.tex`, with each name of the subfile on a separate line:

```
subfile1
subfile2
...
```

and read this file line by line in the subfile, comparing if the current line is empty or equal to `\jobname`, and if not, add the line `\externaldocument{../current-line/current-line}`.

Is it possible to do this with expl3?

---

Below is a set of files to test. The files are organized as:

```
list.txt
main.tex
subfile-one/subfile-one.tex
subfile-two/subfile-two.tex
```

Below are the file contents.

- list.txt (the last empty line is on purpose)

```
subfile-one
subfile-two
```

- main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
\input{subfile-one/subfile-one.tex}
\input{subfile-two/subfile-two.tex}
\end{document}
```

- subfile-one.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr}

% \externaldocument{../subfile-two/subfile-two}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\begin{document}

\section{one}
\label{one}

\ref{two}

\end{document}
```

- subfile-two.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr}

% \externaldocument{../subfile-one/subfile-one}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{document}

\section{two}
\label{two}

\ref{one}

\end{document}
```

Expected behavior:

[image]

and each subfile should contain half of it.

Comment: For clarification: are solutions using LaTeX2e or plain TeX functionality also ok, or are you looking for an expl3 solution specifically? If yes, why?

Comment: And for ease of answering: could you please provide complete compilable versions of mainfile.tex, subfile1.tex, subfile2.tex, list.tex in your question, so that people willing to provide solutions just need to write a file/list processing macro and don't need to implement all of the surrounding code?

Comment: In case non-expl3 syntax is ok you can find an implementation in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111335/testing-lines-read-from-external-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do (untested because of lack of compilable code in the question):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_clear_new:N \l_jinwen_files_tl
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { on } { F }
\ior_new:N \g_jinwen_file_ior
\ior_open:Nn \g_jinwen_file_ior { list.tex }
\ior_map_inline:Nn \g_jinwen_file_ior
  {
    \str_if_eq:onF { \jobname } {#1}
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_jinwen_files_tl
          { \externaldocument { ../#1/#1 } }
      }
  }
\ior_close:N \g_jinwen_file_ior
\exp_last_unbraced:NV \ExplSyntaxOff \l_jinwen_files_tl

\begin{document}
whatever
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this hypothetical code. However, it doesn't seem to work properly. I've added a set of testing files to the question. If everything goes as expected, there should be no warnings for missing labels when compiling the three `.tex` files. But for now the `\externaldocument` doesn't seem to be properly configured.

Comment: @Jinwen you need to 1. include the `expl3`-code in `subfile-two` as well if you want it to work standalone, and 2. you need to compile both `subfile-two` and `subfile-one` standalone so that the aux files exist. If I do both I get the correct contents (and a warning about the labels being defined multiple times...)

Comment: About the "labels being defined multiple times" issue, I suggest using `\exp_args:No \str_if_eq:nnF` instead of `\tl_if_eq:onF`. Comparing them as token list instead of string seems to get the result "false" all the time.

Comment: Also, for unknown reason the `\externaldocument` inside `\ior_map_inline:Nn` does not behave like usual, only if I put it inside a `\AtBeginDocument` it then works normally again. Is it because there is an invisible grouping surrounding it here?

Comment: @Jinwen none that I'm aware of, but we can fix this using a scratch token list instead. The `\tl_if_eq:onF` test gets the wrong result because `\jobname` is a string (my bad).

Comment: And you might have issues with the `\externaldocument` because of the `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: Thank you for the edited answer. About your last point, do you think postpone `\externaldocument` to the hook `begindocument/before` would do? Seems that at that place the ExplSyntax has been turned off. Or just simply add `\ExplSyntaxOff` and `\ExplSyntaxOn` around the `\externaldocument` line?

Comment: @Jinwen my edited answer will only execute the `\externaldocument` after `\ExplSyntaxOff`.